# Replace column names using lookup table, if lookup table contains old column name

Tags: r, lookup, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
test <- data.frame("PLOT.ID" = c(1,2,3),
                "Diameter" = c(1,2,3),
                "tag_id" = c(1,2,3),
                "COL_NA" = c(1,2,3))
```

I also have a lookup table with the old column names that I want to change:

```
lookup <- data.frame(old = c("PLOT.ID", "Diameter"), 
                     new = c("plot_id", "diam"))
```

**How can I use the lookup table to replace only the column names in `test` that appear in `lookup$old` and leave others as they are?**

My method so far removed column names that don't appear in `lookup$old` and replaces them with blanks:

```
test_new <- setNames(test, lookup$new[match(names(test), lookup$old)])
```

Comment: Try with `match` `i1 <- match(lookup$old, names(test));names(test)[i1] <- as.character(lookup$new)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `mapvalues` function from the `plyr` package:

```
test_new <- test
colnames(test_new) <- plyr::mapvalues(colnames(test),
    as.character(lookup$old), 
    as.character(lookup$new))

> test_new
  plot_id diam tag_id COL_NA
1       1    1      1      1
2       2    2      2      2
3       3    3      3      3
```